# How may I append new results from iterating through a list, into a new column in the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, dataframe

Im attempting to create a table as follows, where equities in a list get appended as columns to the dataframe:

**Fundamentals  CTRP    EBAY ...... MPNGF**

price
dividend
five_year_dividend
pe_ratio
pegRatio
priceToBook 
price_to_sales
book_value
ebit
net_income
EPS 
DebtEquity
threeYearAverageReturn

At the moment, based on the code below, only the last equity in the list is showing up:

**Fundamentals     MPNGF**

price
dividend
five_year_dividend
pe_ratio
pegRatio
priceToBook 
price_to_sales
book_value
ebit
net_income
EPS 
DebtEquity
threeYearAverageReturn

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
import pandas as pd
import lxml
from lxml import html
import requests
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime


def scrape_table(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    table = tree.xpath('//table')
    assert len(table) == 1

    df = pd.read_html(lxml.etree.tostring(table[0], method='html'))[0]

    df = df.set_index(0)
    df = df.dropna()
    df = df.transpose()
    df = df.replace('-', '0')

    df[df.columns[0]] = pd.to_datetime(df[df.columns[0]])
    cols = list(df.columns)
    cols[0] = 'Date'
    df = df.set_axis(cols, axis='columns', inplace=False)

    numeric_columns = list(df.columns)[1::]
    df[numeric_columns] = df[numeric_columns].astype(np.float64)

    return df

ecommerce = ['CTRP', 'EBAY', 'GRUB', 'BABA', 'JD', 'EXPE', 'AMZN', 'BKNG', 'MPNGF']

price=[]
dividend=[]
five_year_dividend=[]
pe_ratio=[]
pegRatio=[]
priceToBook=[]
price_to_sales=[]
book_value=[]
ebit=[]
net_income=[]
EPS=[]
DebtEquity=[]
threeYearAverageReturn=[]

for i, symbol in enumerate(ecommerce):     
    yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(symbol)
    balance_sheet_url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '/balance-sheet?p=' + symbol
    df_balance_sheet = scrape_table(balance_sheet_url)
    df_balance_sheet_de = pd.DataFrame(df_balance_sheet, columns = ["Total Liabilities", "Total stockholders' equity"])
    j= df_balance_sheet_de.loc[[1]]   
    j['DebtEquity'] = j["Total Liabilities"]/j["Total stockholders' equity"]
    k= j.iloc[0]['DebtEquity']

    X = yahoo_financials.get_key_statistics_data()
    for d in X.values():
        PEG = d['pegRatio']
        PB = d['priceToBook']
        three_year_ave_return = d['threeYearAverageReturn']

    data = [['price', yahoo_financials.get_current_price()], ['dividend', yahoo_financials.get_dividend_yield()], ['five_year_dividend', yahoo_financials.get_five_yr_avg_div_yield()], ['pe_ratio', yahoo_financials.get_pe_ratio()], ['pegRatio', PEG], ['priceToBook', PB], ['price_to_sales', yahoo_financials.get_price_to_sales()], ['book_value', yahoo_financials.get_book_value()], ['ebit', yahoo_financials.get_ebit()], ['net_income', yahoo_financials.get_net_income()], ['EPS', yahoo_financials.get_earnings_per_share()], ['DebtEquity', mee], ['threeYearAverageReturn', three_year_ave_return]]
    data.append(symbol.text)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Fundamentals', symbol])
    df
```

Seeking your kind advice please as to where may i have gone wrong in the above table? Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your df outside of your for loop.  Your code as currently written will recreate a new df for every loop.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I've tried calling df outside of loop now, but still get only the values from the last equity in the list.. also tried to concat but it just repeats the values from the last equity in the list.    #df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Fundamentals', symbol]) for symbol in enumerate(ecommerce)], ignore_index=False)

Comment: (I wish I could just rewrite the code for you but I cannot spend that time right now)...I will say the next thing you can try is to rename the df in your for loop to be "results" instead of "df".  You could be getting unintended consequences from having a local variable in your scrape_table function being the same name as a variable in your for loop (df).

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I've done that, now i see a nicely framed data table, although the results that populate this table still comes from only the last equity, not sure why I cant fill the values of the other equities to the table